# Concatenate elements on a list separated by a character

Tags: scala

I have the following list:

```
val aList: Seq[String] = List("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

I want to return the string: `"A-B-C-D-E"`. The following code does it:

```
aList.map(_ + "-").fold("")(_ + _).dropRight(1)
```

But as you can see, with the map and the fold operations, I need to drop the last "-" character at the end. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it on a way that is simpler and more direct (without using the `dropRight` function).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just do this: `aList.iterator.mkString("-")`

Comment: @Jesper the `iterator` is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: aList.mkString("-")
    //  res12: String = A-B-C-D-E